# Rails - Client Side Validations - none displayed form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, client-side-validation

Im using 'client_side_validations' gem to validate my form. However it has `display: none` attribute at the beginning and I change it to `display: block` after jquery click action.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#thumb_up').on('click', function () {
    $('.vote_form').css('display', 'block');
  });
});
```

Unfortuantely then it does not work. When I use `visibility` instead it works. How to run it using `display: none` attr?

Comment: try using `$('.vote_form').show()`

Comment: unfortunatelly the same effect

Answer (score 0):

The gem (see the [source code](https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations/blob/master/coffeescript/rails.validations.coffee#L274)) only initializes client side validation for visible inputs, i.e. elements that takes up space on the page.

After showing your form, you must enable client side validations:

```
$('.vote_form').enableClientSideValidations();
```

https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations#enabling

Comment: I've also read it and it does not work for me. When it works the gem renders input like: //<input data-validate="true" type="text" value="" name="user[email]" id="user_email">// but in my case there is not `data-validate="true"` part.